# Questions on "does baptism wash away sins" looking at Luke 3:3 and Acts 2:38

Tags: sin, baptism, forgiveness, regeneration

The passages of Luke 3:3 and Acts 2:38 have very similar language and according to Peter in Acts he is baptizing the same baptism as John, only in Jesus name.

> Luke 3:3 says, "And he went into all the region around the Jordan, proclaiming a baptism of > repentance for the forgiveness of sins"

> Acts 2:38 says, "Repent and be baptized every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ for the forgiveness of your sins, and you will receive the gift of the Holy Spirit"

Both verses speak about repentance and baptism and both verses say they are "for the forgiveness or remittance of sin"

So what does "for forgiveness of sins" mean.

Now Acts 2:38 is often interpreted to mean that the act of baptism is necessary to wash away sin, however given the same language in both verses that means that Johns baptism also washes away sin.

My question is, can this language be translated any other way that does not imply that baptism actually forgives sins or is when sins are forgiven.

Comment: You are asking several questions here. 1. What is the difference/similarities in the baptism of John and that of the apostles of Jesus Christ ? 2. What does 'forgiveness' mean ? 3. What does 'remission' mean ? 4. How does baptism 'wash away sins' ? 5. How does baptism wash away sin _itself_ ? 5. How does blood wash away sin ? 6. How is there forgiveness/remission by means of blood ?  All these are very valid and important questions and they need to be firmly answered, one by one, logically and in an organised and structured manner. This is called 'The Gospel'. Welcome to SE-C. I wish you well.

Comment: Please do not feel discouraged at the closure of your question for purely administrative (multiple questions) reasons. All your questions are answered fully in my [book](https://belmontpublications.co.uk/books/the-burden-of-sins/) '_The Burden of Sins_' which is free of charge on my website. See my profile for more details. Kind Regards.